# Sort collection of object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, sorting

I know I can use something like User.sort {|a, b| a.attribute <=> b.attribute} or User.find and order, but is it a way like comparable interface in Java, so every time I called sort on User object it will do sort on the predefined attributes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by defining the `<=>` method for your objects. That way, you should be able to just say: `collection.sort` for non-destructive sort, or `collection.sort!` for in-place sorting:

So, example here:

```
class A
   def <=>(other)
      # put sorting logic here
   end
end
```

And a more complete one:

```
class A
    attr_accessor :val
    def initialize
       @val = 0
    end

    def <=>(other)
       return @val <=> other.val
    end
end

a = A.new
b = A.new
a.val = 5
b.val = 1
ar = [a,b]
ar.sort!
ar.each do |x|
  puts x.val
end
```

This will output `1` and `5`.

Comment: I just found that ruby has Comparable module and we can implements all comparison operations with in one method define <=>. Using it just include Comparable in any class you want.

Comment: It's the same thing. If you include Comparable, you still need to define your own `<=>` method. The thing is, you'll only have one extra line of code, which won't serve to any purpose.

Comment: It does serve some purposes, that is in case you want your Objects to have comparison operations (< <= == >= >). Instead of define it separately, you just include Comparable and define your own <=> method.

Comment: This is true. However, I was refering to your question alone.